# Exibir caixa de dialogo na tela em primeiro plano mesmo se a janela estiver em segundo plano

Tags: java, swing

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação aonde ele trabalha com horarios, o usuario irá deixar o problema rodando e vai continuar usando o pc normalmente e quando der um certo horário irá tocar um som (já está sendo feito) e apareceria uma caixa de dialogo avisando sobre o horário. Mas eu queria que essa tela ficasse em primeiro plano, aparecesse na tela do usuario sem ele precisar clicar na aplicação.

Exemplo: quando eu clicasse no botão do swing ele iria iniciar o "`conta()`". Depois que o LOOP FOR dentro desse "`conta()`", fosse terminado ele irá aparecer a caixa de dialogo. Só que quero que essa caixa apareça na tela do usuario mesmo a aplicação estando MINIMIZADA, no caso você não irá precisar clicar na sua aplicação pra ver a mensagem, ela simplesmente aparecerá pra você, sem precisar ir até ela, entende?

Por exemplo, deixo essa aplicação rodando depois de clicar no botão e vou utilizar outra coisa no pc (e ele fica minimizado), e quando fosse pra aparecer a caixa de dialogo ele iria mostrar na tela normal, sem precisar maximizar a aplicação.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javaapplication1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Hamon
 */
public class asd extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form asd */
    public asd() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(198, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        conta();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(asd.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(asd.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(asd.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(asd.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new asd().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    **public void conta(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){

            System.out.println(i);
        }**

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mensagem", "Titulo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Texto da mensagem", "titulo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);` não resolve?

Comment: Não, eu preciso abrir a aplicação novamente, só assim pra visualizar. Eu gostaria que ele aparecesse sem precisar ir diretamente ver se tem alguma mensagem, ele iria simplismente aparecer na tela.

Comment: Então adicione um **[mcve]** da sua aplicação para que seja possivel visualizar o problema.

Comment: Na verdade não precisa nem do código, mas é o seguinte por exemplo, deixo esse for rodando, ele vai demorar um pouco pra terminar, e quando (imagine que isso é um swing, que quando eu clico em um botao ele inicia o loop), depois disso eu iria minimizar a tela e usar  o pc normalmente, eu queria que o dialogo aparecesse na minha tela sem eu precisar clicar na aplicacao (que está minimizada) para ver entende?

Comment: Sem ver o código fica complicado sugerir algo, a pergunta ficaria ampla e poderia ser fechada, pois há várias forma de se fazer isso. Seria interessante adicionar um exemplo que possa ser reproduzido, da tela de onde você quer fazer isso.

Comment: Pronto, está editado. Estou aprendendo a lidar aqui ainda. Se puder tentar novamente me ajudar com a principal questão, agradeço.

Comment: Testei o código com a tela minimizada e a caixa de mensagem apareceu mesmo com a janela estando minimizada. JOptionPane sempre aparece em primeiro plano.

Comment: Ok, tente desta forma agora. Clique no botão e então clique em outro icone, por exemplo do navegador (sem clicar no de minimizar), verá que agora não aparece.

Comment: Consegue me ajudar ainda diegofm?

Comment: Estou fazendo uns testes, só um momento e já posto uma solução.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme sugerido [nesta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957032/5524514), é possível fazer da seguinte forma, utilizando [**`JDialog`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html):

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
javax.swing.JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(this, "Aviso");
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

O método [`setAlwaysOnTop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-) define que esta janela de diálogo fique acima de todas as outras, embora isso não possa ser garantido, pois quem decide é o sistema operacional. Em testes aqui no windows, funcionou perfeitamente, mas pode não funcionar desta forma em outros sistemas.

Adaptando para o exemplo do teu código, ficaria da forma abaixo, caso esta janela seja utilizada apenas nesta tela:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Teste extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Teste() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(198, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        conta();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Teste().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void conta(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++){

            System.out.println(i);
        }
        showCustomAlert("Terminado");
    }

    public void showCustomAlert(String message){

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(message);
        javax.swing.JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(this, "Aviso");
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        //coloca a janela na frente após fechar o aviso
        this.toFront();

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Repare que, para exibir uma mensagem ao `JDialog`, é necessário passar uma `String` a instancia do `JOptionPane`.

Se for utilizar em outras classes, o mais interessante é criar uma `JDialog` a parte, no site há alguns [exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdialog) de como manipular essas janelas de dialogo.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54265/discussion-on-answer-by-diegofm-exibir-caixa-de-dialogo-na-tela-em-primeiro-plan)